# Find stores missing at least one item in a list of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following (simplified) table:

```
------------------
|store|item|value|
------------------
|    1|   1|    4|
|    1|   2|    3|
|    1|   3|    0|
|    2|   2|    2|
|    2|   3|    1|
|    3|   4|    2|
```

I want to know which stores are missing any item from a list of item, and I want to know the value for the items they do have.  The list of items is normally larger than above, but is usually only searched by a few at a time.

So let's say I want to know which stores are missing any of item 1 or item 2.  I would like results such as this ideally:

```
-------------
|store| 1| 2|
-------------
|    2| 0| 2|
|    3| 0| 0|
```

Store 1 is not returned because it has entries for both item 1 and item 2 where the value is greater than 0 for each.  Initially I only needed the store ids but putting the items as columns with their values in the rows would be very helpful for what we need now.  I started out with a monstrosity of 3 queries union'd together that worked okay to give the list of stores (first column).  As I was thinking about how to add the other columns I decided to see if I could simplify the query.  I came up with this:

```
select store
from table t1
where
(select count(*) 
 from (
   select store,item 
   from table t2 
   where t2.item in (1,2) and value != 0
   group by item,store
 ) t3 
 where t3.store = t1.store
) != 2
```

It does not perform as well as my first longer query though, and it doesn't give me the columns I'd like.  The idea was to get a count of each store's matching unique items and if that count did not match the number of items queried for then return that store because it was missing at least one item from the list.

Any pointers or help on how to achieve the desired results would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per store, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select store,
       sum(case when item = 1 then value else 0 end) as item1,
       sum(case when item = 2 then value else 0 end) as item2
from table
group by store
having least(item1, item2) = 0;
```

This assumes that all stores have at least one item of any type.

Comment: This is great, thank you!  I changed the last line to having least(item1, item2) = 0; so that I could get the results where at least one of them was zero, which is what I care about in this case.  Unfortunately the query takes quite a while to run.  Do you have any optimization tips or is it just trying to build a decent index for the query?